# Java web start - Version problems

Tags: java, java-web-start

I've decided to make my app java web start, i prepared the .jar file and .jnlp.
Here is .jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
    codebase="http://www.mypage.com/jar/" 
    href="BoxChat.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>BoxChat</title>
        <vendor>Kitty</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://www.mypage.com/jar/"/>
        <jar href="chat.jar" main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="BoxChat"
         main-class="chat.class"
         width="320"
         height="240">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

It crashes and says that i have no java 1.6 installed, but im SURE that i have it. What is the problem? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Did you add JAVA_HOME in environment variable?

Comment: no, i use eclipse, how to do that?

Comment: Window--Preferences--Java--installed JREs--> Check which java version you have. If it not 1.6, you need to click on Add--> select your jdk 1.6 location. Restart your eclipse.

Comment: That JNLP is invalid.  Be sure to check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look through the tips in [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html).  Look particularly for references to the *JNLP Runtime Settings* dialog.

[image: JLNP Runtime Settings dialog]

Answer (score 1):

When you install java usually there are two steps. The first is **jdk** and when it is finished then it asks you whether you would like to install **jre**. And webstart requires JRE installed correctly. So I would simply sujest to install it again and make sure that you perform the second step (**jre**).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is with the below line:

```
<j2se version="1.6+" href="http://www.mypage.com/jar/"/>
```

You need to specify the vendor url only if you want to request a specific JRE version for example 1.4.2_04. Remove the href attribute and re-try.