# use a specific jre for an applet

Tags: plugins, applet, java

after having a problem with the java 7u25 update with streaming video in an applet, I'd like to ask if it's possible to use a jre that is located in the file system and not as browser's plugin, the user will get it one time to a specific folder and then keep using it with the applet.
Is it realistic? will it interfere with the browser's java plugin?

Comment: Yes, that's have to be embedded in the web page, we thought maybe there's a way we can use a copied jre and point to the folder, as jitsi does (running even if there's no java installed), but jitsi works as a native desktop app, so that's the difference?

Comment: *"that's the difference?"*  Basically.  Anything that comes wrapped in a browser window becomes wrapped up in Java *security* as it exists for the latest version installed.  That security has come to slowing or blocking the request for older versions of the JRE, especially if they are lower than the lowest know 'secure' version.  In recent times, that would be ..well 1.7.0_25 alone.  At least for the moment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it realistic?

Not really.  It used to be that an applet deployed using Java Web Start could be launched in any [JRE version](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) installed on the user's system, but security updates have Oracle thinking the user should now only be using the latest JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Applets are, typically donwloaded and run in the web `browser`,So Not possible with out browser `java` plugin(`JRE`).

[An overview by Oracle the how they work  with browsers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so you say I can't use a private jre from an applet?

Comment: *"..use a private jre from an applet?"*  Not anyway that *I* know of..  I'd have up-voted this answer except I got confused at *"So Not possible with out browser `jar`."* ..Huh?  Particularly the last two words.  A jar of an applet will make no difference. And how exactly does the jar relate to a browser in that sentence? ..  Can you phrase it another (that is hopefully more clear) way?

Comment: @AndrewThompson My bad Thompson,Edited.I have to write JRE,I wrote `jar`  ,which made a huge difference.

Comment: @DimaOrman As Andrew said,No way to use.Assuming   `private jar` in the sense,You are to refer the jar on system class path.No way.

Comment: Great edit.  :)  Have to admit that sometimes later as I am reading an answer again, I think..  'Wait a second, that bit is *complete* nonsense with the exact words I used! What I *meant* to write was..'  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Besides to what the other said (is this wise?), there is the possibility to specify an exact java version in the JNLP file (if your are using one with your applet). Have a look at the [java (or j2se)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) element. There you can specify the exact java version and if it is not installed you can specify a downloadlink (href) from where that version will be downloaded and installed from. The documentation states:

> Exact product versions (implementation versions) may also be specified. by including the href attribute. For example, 1.3.1_07, 1.4.2, or 1.5.0-beta2 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. For example, `<j2se version="1.4.2" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/
>   or <j2se version="1.4.2_04" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>`

Some more information is available [here](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html#enable).

However be aware, that this mechanism is not unproblematic as these posts indicate: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802577/webstart-runs-with-wrong-version-of-jre/9803340#9803340),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175453/jnlp-should-use-a-specific-java-version-but-error-results).

Comment: unfortunately we are not using jnlp with our applet, and we are still stuck on the 7u25 security fix bug, our video is not working (only locally), I haven't encountered a fix yet after numerous tries to go around, can someone suggest a way to resolve it?