# How does Java Webstart choose which Java bits n' pieces to run?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I just web-started my Java application on Windows like this:

```
> jdk1.8.0_72\bin\javaws http://myserver/myapp.jnlp
```

Notice that I am using the javaws binary from jdk8u**72**.  While my app was starting, I saw all sorts of evidence that my app was picking up most, but not all jars from here:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77
```

I know this because my app prints the jars it is loading to the console.  My app also prints the value of System properties `java.version` and `javafx.version`, so I know their values are:

```
java.version=1.8.0_77
javafx.version=8.0.72
```

That can't be good.

So, I retroactively inspected the value of environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and saw this:

```
> echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\blah\blah\blah\jdk1.8.0_11
```

Holy crap!  Neither 72 nor 77, but **11**!

My JNLP file requests the Java and JavaFX resources in this manner:

```
<resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="8.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+" .../>
    ...
</resources>
```

I wonder if anyone out there can explain the logic that Java Webstart uses to find the jars it will end up using, how this situation can be avoided.

I thought for sure that `JAVA_HOME` or that starting a particular `javaws` binary would do the trick, but apparently not.

**Update:** No, this is not a duplicate of [Webstart runs with wrong version of JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802577) as I am not using the Browser, but invoking the `javaws` binary directly.  Furthermore, I am not only getting the wrong JRE, but bits and pieces from two different JREs!

**Update:** Apparently, this has little or nothing to do with Webstart.  I downloaded all the jars, configured `CLASSPATH`, and started my application in this way:

```
> java -jar myapp.jar
```

And I see the same behavior.  So, I did this to see which `java` I am actually running:

```
> where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\blah\blah\blah\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe
```

If I spell out exactly which `java.exe` I want, everything is uniform.  If I allow `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` to start my app (what is it this thing?!?) my JVM runs with bits and pieces from two different JREs.

Comment: It typically uses a JRE at runtime; the JDK contains the compiler. The JRE contains all that is necessary to run Java class files; the JDK adds a compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webstart runs with wrong version of JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802577/webstart-runs-with-wrong-version-of-jre)